# Want to state to the authorities there is no intention to make UK a de facto home

Tags: united-kingdom

I have tried but am unable to find out the rules for visitors to a foreign country.

If I study for a 6 year MBBS (medical) course at a University in the United Kingdom, and consider my parents wish to visit me every 6 months till I finish my degree.

Now, as you might be knowing, the UK allows visitors up to a maximum of 6 months at a time/every 12 months. There is also a point they mention that visitors should have a genuine intention to return to their home country after their trip to the UK. Also, there are 2, 5 and 10 year multiple entry visas as well (the long-term Standard Visitor visa), but again, 6 months at a time/every 12 months.

If visitors stay every 6 months of a year to visit the UK and apparently make UK their de facto "home", they could potentially be taken very seriously. Visitors must not intend to use this to make UK their de facto home.

My question is whether the UK permits parents of students studying in the UK to accompany them for 6 months a year (that is the maximum limit allowed for visitors) till they finish their degree (in this case, a 6 year long Bachelor of Medicine, Bachelor of Surgery (MBBS) degree)? The parents **do not** intend to game the system and make UK their de facto home (though it might seem so for the duration of those 6 years). Instead, they just plan 6 month trips to the UK every year till their child finishes the degree. Their intention **isn't to make UK their home.**

Can the UK ban my parents from coming to the UK if they notice a regular pattern of coming to the UK every year (and utilizing the entire 6 months duration every time they come)? Is there anything out there (like a declaration statement or so) where my parents can state that they **do not wish to live in the UK permanently,** and this pattern is merely temporary until I finish my 6 year degree? The reasons they will use the full 6 months limit are humanitarian and affectionate. They just want to be with me as much as they can. No intention to game the system or unlawfully invade UK's spaces. Can they explain this to the relevant authorities beforehand so that they are not banned from coming to the UK in the middle of my degree?

Thank you and kindest regards.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the UK stance. Visitor rules do not mention “6 months out of every 12”, only admittance for up to 6 months on any one visit. Regular visits of 6 months do not fit the typical visitor profile. What ties to their home country do your parents have? How can they spend so much time away?

Comment: You initially state that they wish to visit you every 6 months, and then that they want to stay for 6 months every year. That’s quite different. But it really depends on their situation. The UK border force probably have no problem with a billionaire staying in the UK and spending money there for a majority of the year. They do have a problem with people living and working in the UK while not allowed. As @Traveller asked, how can they spend so much time away?

Comment: During a normal 6 month period much of your time and attention will be needed for your studies. You will have friends and study-partners your own age. It may be better to schedule a couple of vacations each year during which you spend most of your time with your parents, perhaps traveling around the UK.

Comment: Thank you all. My parents do not do traditional jobs as such, their income is not based on working at a particular place everyday. Also, their are enough family ties as well like the Principal Home and business ownership. Thanks again!

Comment: @jcaron I meant the latter thing. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Jay Shah Without wishing to sound negative “no traditional job, an income that doesn’t require them to be in any particular place, and house/business ownership that allows them to be absent for 6 months at a time” don’t sound very much like a compelling set of ties to home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can the UK ban my parents from coming to the UK if they notice a regular pattern of coming to the UK every year (and utilizing the entire 6 months duration every time they come)?

Visitor rules do not mention “6 months out of every 12”, only admittance for up to 6 months on any one visit.  That pattern of visiting is not typical. If entering visa-free, the chance of your parents being denied entry could increase with each successive visit. If they can show they qualify for a long term visa and explain the intended pattern of their visits when applying, the chance of problems at the border is much less but possibly not zero.  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101409/requirements-for-long-term-uk-standard-visitor-visa-2-5-10-years/101413#101413 See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85123/can-i-live-in-the-uk-for-a-long-time-through-repeat-visits

> Is there anything out there (like a declaration statement or so) where my parents can state that they do not wish to live in the UK permanently, and this pattern is merely temporary until I finish my 6 year degree?

The eligibility requirement when applying for a Visitor visa is to show that the applicant will leave the UK at the end of their visit. Typically that is met by demonstrating compelling ties to home eg a job, dependent family. There’s no extra ‘declaration’ that would carry any additional weight, given that by applying for entry / a visa, they are committing to complying with the Immigration Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules